# How do I create a system_clock::time_point from a UTC timestamp's components (Y,M,D, h,m,s,ms)

Tags: c++, time, std

I am reading some data from an external source that is providing me with a UTC time stamp broken down into its constituents to millisecond precision, i.e. I get year, month,day, hour, minute, second and millisecond as integers. How do I (efficiently) create a system_clock::time_point that represents this time?

Comment: Did you have a look at `std::chrono` already?

Comment: Yes, the reason I am posting is because I could not find a way to do this by reading the std::chrono documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most efficient way is to use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only, single-header, date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h):

```
#include "date/date.h"
...
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
int Y, M, D, h, m, s, ms;
...
system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days{year{Y}/M/D} + 
                              hours{h} + minutes{m} + seconds{s} + milliseconds{ms};
```

All the date/time library does for you is convert the Y/M/D triple into a `chrono::time_point<system_clock, days>`.  Then the rest of the expression is all C++11 `<chrono>`.

The [date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h) is now in the C++20 spec, so you can upgrade your code to C++20 by simply removing `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`.

If for whatever reasons you can't use the [date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h), nor upgrade to C++20, then you can code up [`days_from_civil`](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil) yourself with this public domain formula.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! You are a hero for fixing this. How on earth chrono made it through the committee in its present state is beyond me.

Comment: You're welcome!  Yeah, those guys were real bozos: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm ;-)

Comment: Ah, touche. Well, thanks for taking another stab at it.